# Postgis: Point-in-polygon check + feature attributes inheritance

Tags: postgis, sql, point-in-polygon

I have two tables in Postgis 2.1 database:

- Polygon features with a reach attributive information;
- Regular point grid;

I would like to get a SQL query returning the regular point grid with assigned attributive information from the underlying polygon. The output should contain lat, lon columns and an extra column with a given attribute. This will be passed to R scripts throughout the csv files.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select points.*, polygons.* from points 
inner join polygons on
st_intersects(points.geom,polygons.geom);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ST_X(pts.geom) as lon, ST_Y(pts.geom) as lat, poly.attribute 
FROM
  points pts, polygons poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pts.geom);
```

where it is assumed that the attribute you want from the polgons table is called attribute. For non-trivial table sizes, you will want a spatial index on the geometry columns of polygons/points tables.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for, or did you need snap to grid functionality also?